# What does "discursive," mean and how should it be used?

Tags: word-usage

What does "discursive" mean, and how should it be used?

Its definition includes

- digressing from subject to subject; fluent and expansive rather than formulaic or abbreviated; but also,
- proceeding by argument or reasoning rather than by intuition.

Is it simply a word with two, seemingly opposite, senses (i.e., a contronym), or are the two senses somehow reconcilable?

Comment: Uh… please, what suggests your examples are "seemingly opposite"? Wherever they came from the first might be rather tight and second rather loose but otherwise, where is there a problem?